# How to run a basic asynchronous job within sinatra?

Tags: ruby, process, asynchronous, sinatra

I'd like to run a basic asynchronous job

```
exec('curl -0 '+url)
```

from a sinatra app,

I've tried to do that with fork and detach but it seems bogus.

(I'm on windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's and example application from Blake Mizerany at Github: [sinatra-dj](http://github.com/bmizerany/sinatra-dj/tree/master), using DelayedJob as queing mechanism.

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I was looking for, the sinatra-dj example  is really straitforward

Answer (score 1):

What about trying:

```
exec('curl -0'+url) if fork == nil
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work but for a reason I don't quite understand, it works with Thread.new { exec('curl -O'+url) }

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but...

Use [Spork](http://github.com/deadprogrammer/spork)